# Is it possible to recover ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, recovery-mode

Somehow I ended with an unbootable system. I traced the problem to my `/lib` folder and possibly to other system folders

I currently have this [ls -lsha lib lib32 lib64 libx32 usr/lib32/ usr/lib64 usr/libx32/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoqng.png)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/8e5c9899-7541-4ab3-9577-27efa7337808$ ls -lsha lib lib32 lib64 libx32 usr/lib32/ usr/lib64 usr/libx32/
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jun  4  2020 lib32 -> usr/lib32
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jun  4  2020 lib64 -> usr/lib64
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Jun  4  2020 libx32 -> usr/libx32

lib:
total 12K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 14 16:22 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Jul  6 23:26 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Feb 26  2020 terminfo

usr/lib32/:
total 8.0K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Apr 23  2020 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K Apr 23  2020 ..

usr/lib64:
total 8.0K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jan 27 16:29 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K Apr 23  2020 ..
   0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Dec 16  2020 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so

usr/libx32/:
total 8.0K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Apr 23  2020 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K Apr 23  2020 ..
```

My libs folders are empty.

When I try to boot I get this [end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJlMp.jpg)

I'm guessing the only solution is to reinstall the system. Am I correct?

My system partition is OK, I think. As well as my home partition. I ran `fsck` with no problem.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda5: 781569/3751936 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 9781643/15000064 blocks
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda6: 628676/3751936 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 9520496/15000064 blocks
```

I also executed `boot-repair` and I got this link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4CG9s4R9Dr/

Any help will be appreciated.

Is there any way to recover the missing system files?

---

FWIW I think the culprit was a bad Debian package I built myself or the checkinstall program for that matter when I was compiling emacs.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/8e5c9899-7541-4ab3-9577-27efa7337808/usr/local/emacs$ ls -lsha backup-070620211826-pre-emacs-27.2-custom.tgz 
30M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30M Jul  6 23:26 backup-070620211826-pre-emacs-27.2-custom.tgz
```

[It has the same contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zf1j.png) I have in my /lib folder.

Comment: lib32 and libx32 are empty (usually), lib64 just has a link (like you have but probably linked to your running system, with a good /lib). /lib is missing everything except the one terminfo directory.  Backup your files and reinstall is probably the easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind was to: Install a 2nd OS on the same partition, so it overwrites the bootloader, but that was right after I read that the sys is unbootable.